# Does the dash prefix have any effect on the behavior of `ar`?

Tags: unix, static-libraries, unix-ar

In the man page for the `ar` utility, I see the following line.

> If you wish, you may begin the first command-line argument with a
>   dash.

However, there is no further mention of the dash anywhere else in the man page. Since I have seen `ar` commands both with and without the dash, this leaves the unanswered question.

**What effect, if any, does the prefixing the first command-line argument with a `-` have?**

Moreover, if I want to maintain portability across systems, is it safer to have the `-` or not have the `-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the `ar` found in GNU `binutils`, not using the dash has the very small impact of slowing down the startup of your processing.

If you examine the source code of said beast, you'll see very early on in the startup a call to `decode_options()` with the following code:

```
/* Convert old-style tar call by exploding option element and rearranging
   options accordingly. */

if (argc > 1 && argv[1][0] != '-')
{
    int new_argc;       /* argc value for rearranged arguments */
    char **new_argv;    /* argv value for rearranged arguments */
    char *const *in;    /* cursor into original argv */
    char **out;         /* cursor into rearranged argv */
    const char *letter; /* cursor into old option letters */
    char buffer[3];     /* constructed option buffer */

    /* Initialize a constructed option.  */

    buffer[0] = '-';
    buffer[2] = '\0';

    /* Allocate a new argument array, and copy program name in it.  */

    new_argc = argc - 1 + strlen (argv[1]);
    new_argv = xmalloc ((new_argc + 1) * sizeof (*argv));
    in = argv;
    out = new_argv;
    *out++ = *in++;

    /* Copy each old letter option as a separate option.  */

    for (letter = *in++; *letter; letter++)
    {
        buffer[1] = *letter;
        *out++ = xstrdup (buffer);
    }
```

So, if you provide an old-style option such as with `ar pax diablo`, it will auto-magically turn that into `ar -p -a -x diablo` before continuing. By the way, `pax` is probably *not* a valid option set, I've just used it because I'm too lazy to go look at the `man` page - but apparently I have no issue spending an inordinate amount of time explaining my decision :-)

In terms of maximum portability then, it appears you would be better off using the non-`-` arguments since GNU `ar` will handle both that *and* the new form, while older `ar` variants will most likely not handle the new form.

But, and this may simply be my CDO<sup>(a)</sup> tendencies, I'd just go ahead and use the new form on the assumption that I don't really want to support systems so old that they don't have the latest GNU stuff.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Just like OCD, but ordered in the correct damn way :-)

Comment: I think the versions of `ar` that don't handle the `-` options have to be _really_ old — as in predating System V Unix, meaning early 80s or 70s.  Similarly with `tar`.  And if I was really quibbling, I'd note that it is not using the dash that slows things up, not using the dash — but my initial impression is that your answer implies the converse.

Comment: @Jonathan, yes, it could be easily read that way. Have clarified.